# how to make a `curl -ki` with python requests library

Tags: python-2.7, curl, python-requests

my working curl is as follows

```
curl -ki 'https://host/api/getData' -H 'authorization: APP-AUTH "<token>"' -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

but doesn't work as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'https://host/api/getData' -H 'authorization: APP-AUTH "<token>"' -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

I cannot replicate it with python requests library, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't what you requested, but have you looked at the `pycurl` library? It has more direct support for curl-style options.

Comment: I did, but contributing to someone elses code base so would love to get requests work

Comment: Make a dict of the headers and pass it to `headers`;  use `verify=False`

Comment: >>> requests.get(url,headers=headers, verify=False)
python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:821: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [401]>

Comment: headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'APP-AUTH "<token>" ', 'Accept': 'application/json'}